# How to run code in a separate process?

Tags: ruby, process

I'm looking for a solution to spawn code defined in a block or Proc in a separate process.
Something like

```
p = Proc.new do
  File.open('newproc.log', 'w') {
    |fw|
    10.times do
      fw.puts Time.now
      sleep 1
    end
  }
end

# spawn p in a separate process here

# original code continues
```

No process forking, no threading, no storing in an external file. Just executing the block in a standalone process.

Any idea ?

**Update:**
I've to add the block does not depend on anything defined in the calling process.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Because the original process is "fat", ie. occupies a lot of memory and forking would duplicate things.

Comment: Why not put it in another script and call that instead?

Comment: @squiguy You can save the code in an external file and pass it to the ruby interpreter f.E.

Comment: @squiguy Looking for a solution to create such processes on the fly, if possible.

Comment: @DavidUnric In modern Unices, `fork` has copy-on-write optimization, so your new process will use very little new memory.

Answer (score 3):

On Unix-based systems, [`fork(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fork) is the only way to create a new process. You must have the ability to fork to accomplish what you're describing.

If you're trying to avoid forking because the parent process is "fat" and occupies a lot of memory, you may be able to avoid duplicating memory by using a version of Ruby (such as [Ruby 2.0](http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/3/23/why-you-should-be-excited-about-garbage-collection-in-ruby-2-0)) which implements [Copy-on-Write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write). And threads utilize much less memory than a separate process, so threading is certainly worth considering.

**Edit**

A solution using `fork` might look like this:

```
p = Proc.new do
  File.open('newproc.log', 'w') {
    |fw|
    10.times do
      fw.puts Time.now
      sleep 1
    end
  }
end

# spawn p in a separate process here
fork { p.call }

# original code continues
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I fork the code in block from the parent of the main process ? Something like ```Kernel::spawn``` but for independent block of ruby code.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve forking from parent of the main thread like ```(get_parent_process).fork { p.call }``` ?

Comment: You don't need to specify a target for the `fork` call since its a method in the [Kernel](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-fork) module, so you should be able to simply run `fork { p.call }` and it will be forked _from_ the parent process. (The process which invokes `fork` is always the parent process)

Comment: I had to write ```(get_parent_of_the_current_process).fork { p.call }``` to make things more clear. I'm targeting shell that originaly spawned the *main process* .

Comment: Oh, you're hoping to make the new process a _peer_ (i.e. sibling) of the process that is calling `fork`? That's not possible. If the process which calls `fork` finishes and exits, then the child process will be moved to a child of `init` or whatever is the systemwide base process. But I don't believe its possible to move a child process to be a child of another process.

Comment: If I do what you've suggested, I get a subprocess occupying 372 MB of memory, whereas the original process consumes 455 MB. But if I save the block in a file and execute it with a standalone ruby interpreter it takes about 5 MB only.

Comment: What if you just had a simple shell script or lightweight Ruby script to simply invoke both scripts? Then it would have the process graph you're talking about, since both invocations would be peers/siblings of each other

Comment: Ok, if it is *not* possible to create a sibling process then I'm forced to do it like suggested in your last comment. Just asked if possible to do such things more comfortable.